# Issue with Xcode "No matching provisioning profiles found"

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

when I click on  Fix issue button, it didn't get resolved and it pops out with sentence "Creating a provisioning profile requires one or more devices to be registered with your team.  Connect a device to your Mac to add it to your team." 
what should I do to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Sign in with your developer account in xcode. That will set your team and also download relevant provisioning profiles

Comment: Create a developer account.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
in "build settings"--"code signing"
change "code signing identity" to "Don't code sign"
change "provisioning profile" to "Automatic"

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to have developer account to run and debug on your own device (iOs 9+).

Go to **Build Settings** > **Code Signing**, set **Code Signing Identity** as *iOS Develope*r and **Provisioning Profile** as *Automatic*.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Build Settings** > **Code Signing**, set **Code Signing Identity** as **"iOS Developer"** or **"iOS Distributor"** as your need and **Provisioning Profile** as **Automatic**.

your problem will be solve by doing this.

and if you want to run app in your device and your device iOS version is **iOS9** or **above** then you can run app in your device without provisioning profile.